# Subprocess gone sleeping with python multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I wrote a data analysis program with python's multiprocessing library for parallelism. As I don't need to control the subprocess in detail, I used the multiprocessing.Pool for simplicity.

However, when running the program, I find all the sub-processes fall into status S(SLEEPING) after a short period of active(Running) state.

I investigated the `wchan` of the processes. The parent process and all but one sub-processes are waiting for `_futex`, the other one is waiting for `pipe_wait`.

Some information about my program:

1. I used `multiprocessing.Pool#map` to distribute the tasks.
2. The sub-process task contains disk IO and high memory usage. During the course of the program, the sub-process memory cost may exceed the memory capacity (32 sub-processes each takes at most 5% memory). The disk space is ample.
3. The arguments and return values of the mapped function are not very large in size (just the filenames of the file to be processed, to be specific).
4. I didn't explicitly create any pipe in my code.

This is the code skeleton of my program.

```
# imports emitted
def subprocess_task(filename):
  read_the_file(filename) # Large disk IO
  process_the_data() # High memory cost
  write_the_file(new_filename) # Large disk IO
  return newfile_name

if __name__=="__main__":
  files=["","",...] # The filename of files to process, len(files)=32.
  p=multiprocessing.Pool(32) # There are more than 32 cores on the computer.
  res=p.map(subprocess_task,files)
  p.close()
  # Do something with res.
```

So I want to know why the processes stuck in such a state(especially the `pipe_waiting` one)? Does it have anything to do with the high memory usage, and how do I solve it?

Much thanks!

Comment: first try with `Pool(1)` to see if single process will work. Next you can check if problem is with `Pool(2)`. Maybe you use code which block access to some resources and other process wait for resource - and they wait forever because other process keep it all time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some efforts digging into pipe(7), `multiprocessing` source code and the log of my troublesome program, I finally identified the problem.

The sole child process which is `pipe_wait` seems suspicious, because of which I wasted hours trying to find the blocking pipe. However, the key problem has nothing to do with pipes.

The problem is solved when I put some `print` reporting the `pid` at some checkpoints in my program. The processes is not same when the tasks are submitted (which I will refer to as **original** processes) and when the program got stuck (referred as the **stuck** processes). One of the original 32 child processes is missing in the stuck processes, and the only stuck process which is `pipe_wait` is not present when the tasks are submitted.

So I can guess the reason now. And the `multiprocessing` source code corresponds with my guess.

As I said, the program costs lots of memory. At some point when the system is out of memory, the [OOM killer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html) kills one of the child processes, selected by some certain [algorithm](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html#toc94). The OOM killer is forcible and the process exited with all the finishing undone, which includes the communication with the `multiprocessing.Pool`.

As the source code indicates, the pool uses one thread to collect the task results, and another to manage the workers. The collector thread passively waits for the result to be sent by the child process, while the worker manager thread actively detects process exit by polling all processes.

Therefore, after the process is killed, the worker manager thread detects it, and repopulates the pool by spawning a new process. As no more task is submitted, the process is `pipe_wait` for some new task. That's the sole `pipe_wait` child process in my problem. Meanwhile, the result collector thread keeps waiting for the result from the killed thread, which will never arrive. So the other threads are also sleeping.

I have no root access to the environment, or this could be further verified by investigating OOM killer log.